# securize database.php Laravel 4.2

Tags: database, security, laravel, laravel-4, config

we need a secured somehow the connection string that is set in the database.php file, were thinking maybe encrypt the credentials or if you think of another idea is welcome, the idea is that there are no explicit credentials in the source code system, Greetings!

Comment: What database are you using? If you're on MySQL 5.6 or newer, you can use [mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) to create an encrypted login path and use that to login instead of credentials.

Comment: usamos SQL Server 2008 y MySQL 5.5

Comment: In that case you can use [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to store sensitive data in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this technically doesn't answer your question about securely storing the details in a repo. However I think it has merit and might prove *more* secure. YMMV.

Instead of looking to do this in the repository, you could have a prepared database.php on the server (with secure perms) containing the DB login credentials, and copy it to the correct location on deploy. This keeps the repo clean, and can be as secure as needed (the file could be encrypted/only available to one user who handles the deploying etc.).